# Meaning of voting on Halacha in a random gathering

Tags: talmud-gemara, beit-din-court, talmudic-methodology

I previously associated "Halachic voting" with an authoritative and representative assembly of rabbis, until I stumbled over the following passage:

> "דְּתַנְיָא: מַעֲשֶׂה בְּרַבִּי יוֹסֵי בֶּן דּוֹרְמַסְקִית שֶׁהָלַךְ לְהַקְבִּיל פְּנֵי רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר בְּלוֹד, אָמַר לוֹ:
> מָה חִידּוּשׁ הָיָה **בְּבֵית הַמִּדְרָשׁ** הַיּוֹם?
> זאֲמַר לֵיהּ, **נִמְנוּ וְגָמְרוּ**: עַמּוֹן וּמוֹאָב מְעַשְּׂרִין מַעְשַׂר עָנִי בַּשְּׁבִיעִית."

> "Rabbi Elazar asked: What novel idea was taught today **in the study hall**?
> Rabbi Yosei ben Durmaskit said to him: **The Sages counted the votes, and concluded** that the halakhot of the Sabbatical Year and tithes should not apply in the lands of Ammon and Moab ..." [Chagigah.3b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.3b.6-7?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=en)

I infer, then, that voting on Halochos was a common procedure in many [random] rabbinic gatherings. BTW, the Gemmorah continues that they voted on an issue that was already decided centuries earlier and R' Elazar already knew the right Halachah. Another example:

> "Rabbi Yannai said: In the group of Sages (חבורה) [who discussed this matter], they counted and concluded that betrothal by another man does not take effect with a yevama. Rabbi Yoḥanan said to him: My teacher, is this not already taught in a mishna?" [Yevamot.92b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.92b.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

See also [Sanhedrin.74a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.74a.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

What is the meaning of such voting? Whom does it obligate?

Comment: Why do you assume that this was a random beit midrash, and not the Sanhedrin? Indeed, consider Yadayim chapter 4, and especially 4:3.

Comment: From many gemaros we see that different batei din rules differently. Maybe because there was no shulchan aruch like work that incorporated all shitos.